# Devise edit_account_password action redirects me to the root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here are my devise routes:

```
devise_for :accounts, :path_names => { :sign_up => "new" } do
  get "sign_in",           :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  get "sign_out",          :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  get "/change_password",  :to => "devise/passwords#edit"
end
```

And the output of my `rake routes`:

```
       account_password POST   /accounts/password(.:format)                {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"create"}
   new_account_password GET    /accounts/password/new(.:format)            {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"new"}
  edit_account_password GET    /accounts/password/edit(.:format)           {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"edit"}
                        PUT    /accounts/password(.:format)                {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"update"}
```

So the change_password route is not in place and `/change_password` just redirects me to the root_path. Please help me understand why or I will hurt myself. Thank you.

Comment: have the same problem, do you find the solution?

Comment: heh, strange, when im log out and trying to reach this page, im get it! wtf...

Answer (score 12):

Okay, im figured out the problem. Edit password is from Recoverable module, it aims to help the user to get his/her password back if its forgotten, and not for a signed in user to change his/her password. You can use registration/edit instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you were talking about behavior after a user changes his password through the above-mentioned routed change password action.  If you are, please consider this question and answer which may either answer your question or give you a heads up for what you may encounter:

[Devise logging out automatically after password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264750/devise-logging-out-automatically-after-password-change/4859004#4859004)