# ActiveAdmin logging out automatically after password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

The title says it all, basically I'm facing the [same problem as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264750/devise-logging-out-automatically-after-password-change), but I'm using ActiveAdmin and I can't fix this problem.

I've tried adding:

```
controller do
    def update
      if current_account.update_with_password(params[:account])
        sign_in(current_account, :bypass => true)
        flash[:notice] = 'Password updated.'
        redirect_to account_path
      else
        render :action => :show
      end
    end
end
```

In the ActiveAdmin register page, but didn't work.

Other solution I've found is setting `config.sign_in_after_reset_password = true` in the devise config file, but I don't see any `devise.rb` file in the initializers. I also tied `self.sign_in_after_reset_password = true` in `admin_user.rb` Model file, but didn't work.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using Devise and there is no `devise.rb` initializer in `config/initializers`?

Answer (score 1):

I think your devise config is somewhere inside `config` directory. If you don't fine one, add the following line in `initializers/devise.rb`.

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.sign_in_after_reset_password = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run the command

`rails db:seed`

This will update you seed.rb file